# Cannot connect to my SMB server on MacOS

Tags: macos, network, sharing, smb

When I connect to my SMB Linux server by running:

`smb://ubuntu`

it shows me 2 shared folders and that's normal. I made the first folder working without a password and that's working fine. The second folder is secured and macOS doesn't ask for a password when I choose to connect to that folder and it shows an error message instead:

```
Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator.
```

How do I establish a connection successfully by getting a prompt to provide credentials (as required)?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Kindly [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/356767/edit) your question and specify the version of macOS that you are running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use WireShark to capture the SMB2 packets and see what's happening.

1. Install home-brew if needed - https://brew.sh
2. Install wireshark `brew cask install wireshark`
3. Get a capture to the IP address of the server going and then filter for SMB2 traffic. You can tip open any responses and see exactly what's happening.

This is much better than just trying another server or another client or trying to look at the Mac console in my experience. If this is overkill, you could open console.app from /Applications/Utilities and see if there are relevant messages / errors at the time when the error is posted to your screen.

Comment: once I installed WIreshark the connection requires the password then everything became well. I don't know the relation. anyway I'd like to thank you

Comment: I can’t say how many times observing the system actually fixes it over my career. Glad it’s sorted @ASIL

Comment: @bmike how do you mean that? Just by checking it begins working? Also for wshark - is there a simple tutorial how to use it?